# How to get count of different value from a same columns in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named VehicleAlerts,
you can see in the below image that there are different type AlertSubCategory such as Pickup/Drop Delay ,Vehicle Stalled ,Vehicle Speeding Geofence Violation. How will I get count of all type of AlertSubCategory of a vehicle?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Conditional Count` to do this

```
SELECT vehicleid, 
       P_D_delay_count = Count(CASE 
                                 WHEN alertsubcategory = 'pickup/drop delay' THEN 1 
                               END) AS, 
       VehicleStalled = Count(CASE 
                                WHEN alertsubcategory = 'VehicleStalled' THEN 1 
                              END), 
       VehicleSpeeding = Count(CASE 
                                 WHEN alertsubcategory = 'VehicleSpeeding' THEN 1 
                               END), 
       Geofence_Violation_count = Count(CASE 
                                          WHEN alertsubcategory = 'Geofence Violation' THEN 1 
                                        END) 
FROM   yourtable 
GROUP  BY vehicleid
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Count` with a `Group By` on both VehicleId and AlertSubCategory will get the data

```
SELECT VehicleId, AlertSubCategory, Count(1) Occurrence
FROM   [table]
GROUP BY VehicleId, AlertSubCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the count of all vehicles in each AlertSubCategory then you can simple group it by AlertSubCategory and take the count as given below.

```
SELECT AlertSubCategory, COUNT(Id) AS Count
FROM VehicleAlerts
GROUP BY AlertSubCategory
```

If you want to get the cout of one vehicle in each AlertSubCategory then use a WHERE clause in this sql query as given below.

```
DECLARE @VehicleId INT = 1
SELECT AlertSubCategory, COUNT(Id) AS Count
FROM VehicleAlerts
WHERE Vehicle = @VehicleId 
GROUP BY AlertSubCategory
```

Change the value of @VehicleId as you required.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT AlertSubCategory,COUNT(*) as norow FROM VehicleAlerts group by AlertSubCategory